# How to create and edit .htaccess and .htpasswd locally on my computer and then upload to my site via ftp?

Tags: ftp, .htaccess, password, .htpasswd

I'm making a website for a client, and I want to make a password protected directory. The problem is my account type only allows FTP, so is there any way to create the .htaccess and .htpasswd files locally on my computer so I can upload them via FTP?

UPDATE:

I made the files on the site @radius mentioned, and I uploaded and renamed them, but now I'm getting the following message:

"The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.htaccess and .htpasswd files are just text file so you can create them locally then upload them
To create a file starting with '.' on windows see http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-faq/
To create encrypted password for .htpasswd files you can use http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: +1, or create a htaccess.txt and htpasswd.txt files, upload them, then `rename` them on the ftp server.

Comment: The website made the files alright, but when I uploaded them and went to a page in the directory, I got "The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request"

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess file ?

Comment: Okay, the tool you linked to works fine. I just entered the wrong thing into ".htpasswd File Location"

("/path/to" instead of "/path/to/.htpasswd")

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Either this site has changed or I'm really dumb, because I literally see an <img> tag of a form, but no interactive form.

Answer (score 2):

You can also download the Apache 2.2 binaries and use `htpasswd.exe` or `htdigest.exe` to generate the `.htpasswd` or `.htdigest` files on windows.

Answer (score 1):

The generator in the accepted answer seems to no longer be active.  However, this one seems to work: https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/htpasswd-generator/

Answer (score 0):

You can always use notepad to create .htaccess and .htpasswd, save them under "ALL FILES". You may not see it under Windows Explorer since Windows see no name but a long extension, but most FTP clients should have no problem showing the files to you and will allow you to upload accordingly.